# Convert string to decimal

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to convert string to decimal separator “.” and “,” insensitive way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094179/best-way-to-convert-string-to-decimal-separator-and-insensitive-way)

I have problem with converting string to decimal.
This is examples, what I've tried: (in comments I put result of each call).

```
decimal myValue = Convert.ToDecimal(59,99) //5999

decimal myValue = Convert.ToDecimal(59,99,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) //5999

decimal myValue = Convert.ToDecimal(59.99) //59.99

decimal myValue = Convert.ToDecimal(59.99,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) //59.99
```

I want get always decimal with fractional part, independent of separator (. or ,)

How I can do that?

Comment: There are number of `SO` threads on this matter. Please use *search* facility here before you post.

Comment: See here - http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/770130-extract-fraction-values-decimal

Comment: `public decimal ConvertToDecimal(string s)
        {
            if (s.Contains(','))
            {
                return decimal.Parse(s.Replace(',', '.'));
            }
            else 
                return SomeDecimalValue;
        }`