# How to limit a textbox to only numbers and a single decimal point on key press event?

Tags: c#, textbox, decimal

Here is my current code it only accepts numbers, what should I add to allow one decimal point?

```
 private void txtPurchasePrice_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
            {
                if (!char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar))
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
```

Comment: `what should I add to allow one decimal point` use a NumericUpDown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what worked for me!

```
  private void txtPurchasePrice_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) &&
        (e.KeyChar != '.'))
    {
            e.Handled = true;
    }

    // only allow one decimal point
    if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to check for "," too.

Comment: the "," character is ignored. The textbox only accepts numbers and a single decimal point character.

Comment: Sure but decimal point is not always ".", it can be "," too. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4094179/1061668

Comment: Oh, you're right! However for my application there is a limit that the txtPurchasePrice can only be 100 (max) so there isn't a need for the "," character

Comment: I am right but for another reason :). You might write `one thousand` as `1,000.00` but also `1000,00` depending on country & computer OS locale. See [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Globalization.CultureInfo(v=vs.110).aspx). This affects (usually throws an error :) e.g. when you try to parse double values and because of locale, it expects certain separator.

Comment: ...and that's just one of the reasons you should just do `double.TryParse()` as suggested by @Jason Which should be accepted answer IMO.

Comment: i want it to only accept numbers from 1-9 without decimals such as 223344,99323232341234 no limit of length. does the first part your answer fulfil that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse the value of the textbox as a number, if it passes allow the input otherwise disallow it.  In other words, don't check the value on a character by character basis, rather, check the entire value after each character is added.

Something similar to the following untested code:

```
private void txtPurchasePrice_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  e.handled = !Double.tryParse(txtPurchasePrice.text);
}
```

Alternatively, you could keep a count of the number of decimals and reject a decimal if the count is 1.

Comment: This won't work properly as it looks at the last text that was in the TextBox, not the current text.